# How do I get rid of Google Duo icon in Menu bar?

Tags: macos, menu-bar

I just tried to download a bunch of different video apps to see which works best in my country and now I'm stuck with this one at the top. When I click on it, the screen shot shows what comes up. How do I remove it?

[image: Video icon]

Comment: Uninstalling the application again and rebooting doesn‘t help?

Comment: That's the thing, it seems to be a Google duo application but I don't have a Duo app downloaded on my Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Install Google Duo, go to its settings, disable menu item, uninstall.

Hold <kbd>command</kbd> while dragging out the icon from the Menu bar.